# I'v got a weird id that got into to my code that cause spacing between elements

Tags: html, css

I've got a weird spacing between elements like my h1 and buttons.
After inspecting it in the console I saw that's an id="text".
I tried to give it margin:0 but nothing. Also I just want to delete it.

HTML:

```
<h1>The Great <br><span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span><br>Color Game</h1>


   <div id="stripe">
     <button id="reset">New colors</button>
     <span  id="messageDisplay"></span>
     <button id="easyBtn" class="selected">Easy</button>
     <button id="hardBtn" class="selected">Hard</button>

 </div>
```

My [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nadav-himmelfarb/pen/zaxWpv)

Comment: I went to your codepen and noticed it has a bunch of "     &nbsp;" inserted inbetween the elements you're saying there's a "strange gap" inbetween. This would force a full empty line of space between the elements. By removing spaces and extra empty lines, and using tab-indentation instead of space indentation, it was fixed in the codepen. I do think it's weird since whitespace should be ignored in html, but using proper indentation at least fixed it for me. Could you try that?

Comment: The nonbreaking spaces are certainly the problem. Nonbreaking spaces won't be ignored in the HTML, and just because they're only descendants of the `body` tag doesn't mean they won't still show.

Comment: Thbak u both. Can you explain waht id &nbsp exactly, Who did I got it and how do i get rid of it?